# Having Trouble Downloading file from firebase storage using react-native-fs

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage, react-native-firebase

I have implemented a way to download file from firebase storage and then saving it into the device.
Below is the code that gets the file url and then runs the download request

```
 const extension = type.split('/')[1];
      const savedToPath = `${DocumentDirectoryPath}/${filename}.${extension}`;

      const headers: Headers = {
        Accept: type,
        'Content-Type': type,
      };

      const options: DownloadFileOptions = {
        fromUrl: url,
        toFile: savedToPath,
        headers,
        connectionTimeout: 10 * 60 * 1000,
        readTimeout: 10 * 60 * 1000,
        progressDivider: 10,
        progressInterval: 100,
        progress: res => this.showProgress(title, res),
      };

      const response = await downloadFile(options);

      const path = await response.promise.then(async res => {
        const { statusCode, bytesWritten, jobId } = res;
        if (res && res.statusCode === 200 && res.bytesWritten) {
          return savedToPath;
        }
        throw new Error(
          `File caching incomplete. Bytes written : ${bytesWritten} Response Code : ${statusCode} JobId : ${jobId}`,
        );
      });
```

now the url is a download link for the firebase storage file. for example
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pangaea-2f1a0.appspot.com/o/media%2F1707074809001_here_gif?alt=media&token=083bd1e8-fa0d-4e82-bb9a-e8a18e412522

I even set the rules in the firebase storage to allow reading from the bucket.

```
rules_version = '2';


service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if false; // Or any other conditions for write operations
    }
  }
}
```

But after doing all of these i end up with a status code of 403 even when i have implemented the rules above. What could possibly be the error.

Below is my error
`Fail caching failed: Bytes written: 0 Response Code: 403 JobId: 3`

I tried making the firebase storage rules public for both read and write. But i still get the same error

Comment: What does `downloadFile` look like?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen 'downloadFile' is a method from react-native-fs

Comment: Link appreciated going forward: https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs?tab=readme-ov-file#downloadfileoptions-downloadfileoptions--jobid-number-promise-promisedownloadresult-

Comment: I don't see what's going wrong, but maybe somebody else does with the extra info.